# Plotly maps not showing in Jupyter Notebook in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, plot, jupyter-notebook, plotly

stacks!
I'm trying to plot a graph using plotly, in Python. Specifically:
Plot: Maps, Bubblemaps, Choropleth..
Python: 3.9.6
Plotly: 4.01
Jupyter Notebook: 7.26
Env Manager: miniconda3
IDE: Ms. Visual Studio Code

I tried to run a code like this:

```
import plotly
import plotly.offline as pyo
pyo.init_notebook_mode()
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as ex
df = ex.data.gapminder().query("year==2007")
fig = ex.choropleth(df, locations="iso_alpha",
                    color="lifeExp", # lifeExp is a column of gapminder
                    hover_name="country", # column to add to hover information
                    color_continuous_scale=ex.colors.sequential.Plasma)
```

which is not my project code, just the example code of Plotly Map that I found on Plotly website (https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/), but it's not showing anything.

P.S: I've tried to install plotly Jupyterlab dependencies from conda, i've also tried to use offline plotly but still nothing comes up. (Only the plot canvas and legend, the map is missing). Although, when I tried to make a bar chart it works. Help me masters!!!!!

Comment: I'd suggest updating to latest version of plotly 5.2.1,  one of the 5.x versions simplified jupytyer integration.   Your code works for me,  but you missed one thing - display the figure!  `fig` at end on juptyer cell to output it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Rob, oh ya I mean, I do include the ```fig.show()``` in my code but I totaly forgot to include that in this question.... XD